# laravel, update table structure but get error table already exist when use php artisan migrate

Tags: php, laravel

I have table and I wanted to update on some columns, or if I wanted to add new column the problem is when I want to use php artisan migrate command gives me error table already exist, also Im using depoly file and the command inside it is **php artisan migrate --force** so hope this is correct or have to add any more command??

```
     public function up()
     {

    Schema::create('payment_methods', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('paymentreference')->unique();
        $table->string('payment_token');
        $table->string('cardnumber'); //updated
        $table->string('cardbin')->nullable();
        $table->string('cardlast4');
        $table->string('cardtype');
        $table->string('expirymonth');
        $table->string('expiryyear');
        $table->string('cardholdername');  //added
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    }
```

Comment: You're using `Schema::create()`  which will ... create the table. To update an already existing table via migrations use `Schema::table()`

Comment: I used Schema::update('payment_methods', function...
then php artisan migrate, I got the same error
("SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 ...

Comment: Not sure if `Schema::update` even exists. If you're still developing/planning your app and can afford to lose all data you can `php artisan migrate:fresh` to start all migrations from the start. (This will drop all tables and create them from scratch, so your data will be lost) If you already have data you cannot lose, create a new migration to add/update those two fields

Comment: This is a very wrong way to add a new column to the existing table using migration. You should create a new migration file and use mentioned `Schema::table()` method to add the new column. Please check [Modifiying columns](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations#modifying-columns) Docs for more information

Comment: so yopu want add coloumn in your table right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To added new or update field like profile in payment_methods.

Try

Run command:

`php artisan make:migration add_profile_to_payment_methods`

And in the `up()` method of the new migration file generated, use `Schema::table()` method to add the new columns or modifying the table.

```
                public function up()
                {
                    Schema::table('payment_methods', function (Blueprint $table) {
                        $table->string('profile')->nullable();
                    });
                }


                public function down()
                {
                    Schema::table('payment_methods', function (Blueprint $table) {
                        $table->dropColumn('profile');
                    });
                }
            }
```

Then run migration to update the table using `php artisan migrate`

Comment: the same error!!! nothing changed!!!  php artisan migrate
Migrating: 2019_12_20_122122_create_payment_methods_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'payment_methods' already exists (

Answer (score 0):

You need a new migration to modify existing table.

Create new migration:

> php artisan make:migration modify_payment_methods_table

Then open the migration file and put following code in there:

```
 public function up()
 {
    Schema::table('payment_methods', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('cardnumber')->change();
        $table->string('cardholdername');
    });
 }

 public function down()
 {
    Schema::table('payment_methods', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('cardnumber')->change(); // todo: if this was not an integer then fix this to be correct type instead of integer to avoid issue in case if you will have to rollback the migration
        $table->dropColumn('cardholdername');
    });
 }
```

After this run

> php artisan migrate

To do this successfully you may need to install additional dependency doctrine/dbal.

You can install that easily with composer:

> composer require doctrine/dbal

Answer (score 0):

You have manipulated or an error has occurred in any of the migrations.

Well, now in the **migrations table**, there isn't a row that contains **create_payment_methods_table** in the migrations column.

As it does not exist, but the table to which the migration refers, if it exists in your database, it fails you, since the process is as follows:

- When you refresh, Laravel reads the migrations table, and executes
  each migration file in order, first executing the down or deletion of
  the table.
- After executing that step in all migrations, go through the UP. When 
  the down of that table does not exist, when arriving at its demo
  file, the up finds that it already exists. And that's why it fails
  you.,

The solution is to delete manually the referenced table and rerun the migration

Comment: do you mean I have to delete the migration table?? I didnt get exactly what do you mean by your solution, please explain it more clear

Comment: Open table migrations. After you open this table and read content it is possible you understand solution. I don't said "delete migration table" I said "delete row have contains create_payment_methods_table"